# Looking for examples of batteries wired in parallel

Tags: batteries, parallel, series

My kids are learning about electricity.    Among their first experiences was connecting D cells to a simple bulb (not LED) and finding out what happens when the 2 batteries were wired in series vs. parallel.  We talked about adding voltages in series, increasing battery life and available current in parallel, and so on.

Then they asked what were some things in the house that use batteries in series and parallel.  We all came up with series examples: toys that use 2 or 3 cells to provide enough voltage to power circuits needing 3-5 volts, and so on.  But are there common household devices that use batteries wired in parallel?  We couldn't think of any.

Note that I am not looking for loads wired in parallel - that comes later.

Comment: You wire batteries in parallel to increase current, so things that need a lot of current like motors. Electric cars, lawnmowers, vacuum cleaners and so on.

Comment: We must be old fashioned then.  Our car and lawnmower use gas and our vacuum plugs into the wall...

Comment: > common household devices that use batteries wired in parallel?<  ... Yes, Battery pack by 4 or 6 Li-Ion ... named "Power Bank" ...

Answer (score 1):

Devices with user accessible battery cells (primary or rechargeable) rarely have them wired in parallel. For obvious performance and safety reasons.

Devices such as powerbanks could very well add capacity by paralleling two or multiple cells and still use the same electronics as single cell powerbank.

A laptop battery pack could have 6 cells, where there are packs of 2 cells in parallel, connected as 3 of those in series.

Comment: "For obvious performance and safety reasons."  This may not be obvious to many...

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen True, but the question wasn't about that but which devices do have them in parallel and a simple reason why such devices are not easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a "household item", [a Tesla EV has many cells in parallel](https://www.greentecauto.com/hybrid-battery/repurposed-batteries/tesla-model-s/tesla-model-s-nca-24v-233ah-5-3kwh-battery-module).